# vertx 2: vertx.eventBus().send(ClassName.ADDRESS, ....) why does it init a new class?

Tags: vert.x

I work on a project based on Vertx the following line:

```
vertx.eventBus().send(MyClass.ADDRESS, requestBody, new Handler<Message<Object>>() {
   ....
}

public class MyClass implements Handler<Message<JsonObject>> { 
   public static final String ADDRESS = "coupons.api.manager";
   ...
   @Override
   public void handle(Message<JsonObject> msg) { 
      ...
   }
}
```

Whereas MyClass.ADDRESS is a static field of type string in the class MyClass, I found out that the line vertx.eventBus(...) creates an object of MyClass and then runs the handle() function.

My question is why? MyClass.ADDRESS is a string, and a static one. How does vertx "know" that it has to create an object from a class that this string is an attribute of?

I looked at the documentation of the send() function: http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/eventbus/EventBus.html#send-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-io.vertx.core.eventbus.DeliveryOptions-io.vertx.core.Handler-

and it says that the first argument in the function is "the address to send it to". OK. But, who said that the address means instantiating this class?

Comment: Are you sure, that `vertx.eventBus(...)` creates an object of `MyClass` because of a static field? Try to replace `MyClass.ADDRESS` with a `"coupons.api.manager"` in `vertx.eventBus(...)` to check, if you'll get object of `MyClass` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small research, and yes. Vertx, behind the curtains, connects all the classes that implement Handler> to the string value they have in the attribute ClassName.ADDRESS.

When the statement:

```
vertx.eventBus().send(MyClass.ADDRESS, requestBody, new Handler<Message<Object>>() {
   ....
}
```

is invoked, a new thread is created and runs the handle method in the class MyClass.